# Name for the ability to accept and react positively to challenges?

Tags: measurement, problem-solving

I am surveying early-stage entrepreneurs. The phenomenon I really want is their ability to clearly see, accept, and positively act on, difficulties -- maybe with their company, maybe their product, and maybe themselves. I expect this will be associated with a sort of generally-well-adjusted nature, not insecure, not defensive, but these aren't directly the variables of interest. Is there something in the literature that defines, explores, and measures, "Ability to accept reality and keep going?" I would be happy to be pointed in many relevant directions.

Similar concepts are all over the place, but I haven't found a single one that nails it. I first looked for an opposite to delusional, or just a low score on a delusion instrument, but the scales for delusion I've found deal with a far more intense and disruptive kind of thing than is relevant to my situation. Psychological resilience is also similar, but again feels like it's more about dramatic trauma, than getting your presentation critiqued -- growth mindset is also close, but it feels like an important component, rather than the whole phenomenon. Grit in general I don't like as a measure because it doesn't capture adaptive problem solving, only bloody-mindedness, and flexibility is critical for early companies.

The thing I have most in mind is really from the mindfulness literature, a sort of "ego-less" enlightenment, but I haven't seen a good scientific treatment of this in problem solving, only for well-being.

Comment: You may want to look at the opposite of [neuroticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroticism) rather than delusion.  There is also [anti-fragile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antifragility), but this might be going too far for your purposes.  I am not sure if the answer you are looking for is in psychology - like you said, it might be something Buddhist, like [equanimity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equanimity).

Comment: As @ArnonWeinberg points out, looking through everything you have explored I feel that you have covered all the bases along the psychology route. The opposite of neuroticism is a good pointer though which you may want to explore. For scientific studies on neuroticism, you may wish to review [this overview from *Science Direct*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/psychology/neuroticism)

Comment: Great, thank you both -- and just to be clear, the opposite of neuroticism is just a low score on a neuroticism scale? There's no separate thing with a different name?